# Koala Sass - Why autoprefix not work?

Tags: css, compilation, sass, koala, autoprefixer

I use Koala App for Sass compilation.

I want to make the automatic addition of prefixes for properties CSS3

[Screenshot my options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6e2t.jpg)

**SCSS:**

```
$radius: 14px;

.test {
    border-radius: $radius;
}
```

**Result CSS (Compile WITH set option "Autoprefix"):**

```
.test {
  border-radius: 14px;
}
```

**Result CSS (Compile WITHOUT set option "Autoprefix"):**

```
.test {
  border-radius: 14px;
}
```

The same result. Why autoprefix not work?

**That's what I want to get after compilation**

```
.test {
  -webkit-border-radius: 14px;
  -moz-border-radius: 14px;
  border-radius: 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Koala's Autoprefixer will only add prefix if they're needed. Apparently `border-radius` is [fully supported by all major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius) and don't need any additional prefix.